# Listen/Watch Azure Blob Storage Containers and download new blobs

Tags: c#, windows-services, containers, listener, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to create Windows Service, that will listen Azure Storage Account (Containers), and download new files to local folders.

I've already created functionality in other direction, which watch (*FileSystemWatcher*) local folders and send files to the same azure storage.

I found that this can be done with JobHost, but I'm not sure how I will listen all containers and download every change on containers?

Regards,
Stefan

Comment: You can use logic app to do this or a webjob. check  blobtrigger + webjob on azure. Otherwsie you can also use eventgrid.

Comment: Is it possible to set blob trigger or event grid locally on some machine, or only on azure function?

Comment: you can debug your blob trigger using the azure function sdk for visual studio but you need to have a blob storage